# React native Image component not working in android

Tags: android, image, react-native

I'm very new to React Native and I'm having problem working with Image.

To simplify my question, I've created a new react native project and just added Image component in index.android.js as below:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

class TestProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Image source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}/>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestProject', () => TestProject);
```

The url inside Image component is copied from [React Native Image documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html).
What am I doing wrong? Can anyone please help me out?

my react native is 0.29.0 , and I haven't tried this in ios yet because right now I need to create an Android app first.

Comment: you need to give width and height of the image to render...as
style = {{height:30, width:30}}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That may be it because I havent tried that yet. i will try setting size of the image and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give height and width of image.

```
<Image source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding style to your image with width and height.

For react native to download the image, get its size and then render it again would result in a poor user experience. You need to specify the dimensions.